# How to cancel print job from printer using Google Cloud Print api

Tags: api, printing, google-cloud-print, google-cloud-print-privet

I'm developing a mobile application using Google Cloud Print apis and I'm able to submit the print job to printer. But If the print job was stopped due to Insufficient  papers or with any technical issue during printing, Then I want to cancel the print job. I'm able to cancel the print job using Google Cloud Print api (https://www.google.com/cloudprint/control from https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/proxyinterfaces#control) but it is showing print job status as cancelled in Google cloud print console, But when I fix the issue at printer side the job is continuing in printer. But my requirement is I need to cancel the job completely from printer also. Please suggest the way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try calling this api:

`https://www.google.com/cloudprint/deletejob?jobid=<job-id-that-needs-to-be-deleted>`

Please refer to: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#deletejob